# Keep type parameter when calling generic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Suppose the following:

```
type GenericFunc<T> = () => Promise<T>

interface FuncWithModifier<T> extends GenericFunc<T> {
  modifier: GenericFunc<T>
}

const wrapFunction = <T> (func: GenericFunc<T>): FuncWithModifier<T> => {
    const modifier: GenericFunc<T> = async () => func()
    return Object.assign(func, { modifier })
}
```

Now I can create functions with a modifier, like this:

```
const stringFunc: FuncWithModifier<string> = wrapFunction(async () => 'foo')
const str1: string = await stringFunc()
const str2: string = await stringFunc.modifier()
```

It also works without an explicit type annotation:

```
const implicitStringFunc = wrapFunction(async () => 'foo')
const str3: string = await implicitStringFunc()
const str4: string = await implicitStringFunc.modifier()
```

What I want now, is a generic function, e.g. something like:

```
// doesn't work, invalid syntax!
const genericFunc = <T = unknown> wrapFunction(async () => null as any)
```

… so that I can use it like this:

```
const unknown1: unknown = await genericFunc()
const unknown2: unknown = await genericFunc.modifier()
const num1: number = await genericFunc<number>()
const num2: number = await genericFunc.modifier<number>()
const bool1: boolean = await genericFunc<boolean>()
const bool2: boolean = await genericFunc.modifier<boolean>()
```

However, it seems that it is not possible to keep the type parameter from the called function (`wrapFunction` above) and instead apply it to the result. Is there another way that I could achieve this?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&module=7#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgMQK7zQHgBUA+KAXigAoBKMkgBSQHsBbFAZwkKIChuV5gyAGYBDNNGy4A6imAALALKMAJiiEpkXKBAAeg+MrawEydJPzEoAb25QozFWo1IAXMcSpMOCzwC+vNEZ4NmAoAHckETBzYBQgsigtCiFvNzgPM28uKjdzGXklVXVNS1ISGzs7QODQhyLnNJNPcy1yETYQXEoaMqgU3GpbSqQIYCwkeCgAeQAjACsINGAAOna2FABzeGTvABpre0dipChfKm5-bmqQqBDUeA3zXO98xSPnPDv+DZJyCKiYnFtu1OmhurQoAByISMRiQ87XUJ3ACMbi+DwSIjCIlkt2A90e3kGiLxSAATGj8d9MdjcejCbhlnUnMhBlcgjcUMwwAAbdCyADKVIe5gS-2i3liQQoIK61Ah0Nh8PZNVJAGZKQSaTjQlzefzgEKCeZiRykfiACya6ltWm67l8tCC4UMtBM96s87cAD03qgykYEDY8EhoTCjCQAGt9vwAG4iPnKW6dYAiHQAQhVNw2TUyXXIhASOEj8EYYXgJHFgOlsrB8t68CwPJ5UHarfgIARZqgxdL5dRPfgJbLk1tOqgOYyXgGXdVvZHFMHw-L2txk9M07dzOOptVjeYA-3M2Qq9C6+aWSPyCIu5u+8XV5OY7Xuc37vqmkfN9nNxmsJ5A5-owPIQCIo6tnaE6vi0QEgWB35ZqEsGLrBoHgVi47nnmW4ekgeCofBbK6GAEahFYvhQL6UDAIw2jwCIMwgdRjBgAAtCBsYQC2GGyNwQA)

Comment: You are able to infer return type from `wrapFunction` argument. Not sure why do you need extra generic. However, if you need, you can try [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV7v5m), but it works only with `any. I just not sure whether you want to use any or not`

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer. The wrapped function should be generic such that it's return value defaults to `unknown` if no type parameter is given. But it should be allowed to override the return value by giving a type parameter. That should work the same for the wrapped function itself and its modifier function.

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
type FuncWithModifier<T> = {
    <R = 'unset'>(): R extends 'unset' ? Promise<T> : Promise<R>
    modifier: <R = 'unset'>() => R extends 'unset' ? Promise<T> : Promise<R>
}

function wrapFunction<R,>(func: () => Promise<R>): FuncWithModifier<R>
function wrapFunction<R,>(func: () => Promise<R>) {
    const modifier = async () => func()
    return Object.assign(func, { modifier })
}


const stringFunc: FuncWithModifier<string> = wrapFunction(async () => 'foo')
const str1 = await stringFunc()
const str2 = await stringFunc.modifier()

const implicitStringFunc = wrapFunction(async () => 2)
const str3 = await implicitStringFunc()
const str4 = await implicitStringFunc.modifier()



const genericFunc = wrapFunction(async () => 42)
const num1 = await genericFunc<number>()
const num2 = await genericFunc.modifier<number>()
const bool1 = await genericFunc<boolean>()
const bool2 = await genericFunc.modifier<boolean>()
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqeV2m)

I have used `unset` default value to check whether generic was provided or not.